# Remove tasksel lamp-server?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, lamp

I was tricked in running `sudo tasksel install lamp-server` on the wrong server (UBUNTU 10.4).

Now I am stuck with a system where Apache won't start because of an `Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80` error.

I now want to remove this task, but documentation for tasksel says you cant use it to uninstall stuff (!!!???).

My question is, where can I see what packages it installed, and how can I get rid of a selection of them (apt-get?). I want to keep Apache, but MySQL, PHP and the other stuff can go...

[edit] I managed to get rid of most of the lamp stack (`/var/logs/dpkg.log` is usefull for recently installed packages). However it did something in a configuration somewhere, and now two Apache intstances start at boottime.

Killing the first one and starting a new one gets rid of the "could not bind at adress..." error. Does anyone know where the startup of the first one is configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command `tasksel --task-packages lamp-server` to see a list of packages for a given task.  Use `apt-get purge (packages)`.